# Jcalender in Swing Java

Tags: java, swing, swingutilities, swingbuilder

// I am creating customize jcalender in swing

//I am facing problem regarding dates set 
//i.e actual month is start from tuesday and it is starting from wednesday
// I am finding problem regarding setting values in calender-model

//Above code is running fine but problem in showing actual dates
//please suggest me to make necessary changes

```
import java.awt.Color;


public class Calendar extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;

     String[] years = { "2008", "2009", "2010" ,"2011","2012","2013","2014"};

      JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(years);

      String[] months = { "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August",
          "September", "October", "November", "December" };

      JList list = new JList(months);

      JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(list);

      CalendarModel model = new CalendarModel();

      JTable table = new JTable(model);

      public Calendar() {
            super();

            getContentPane().setLayout(null);
            comboBox.setBounds(10, 10, 100, 30);
            comboBox.setSelectedIndex(5);
            comboBox.addItemListener(new ComboHandler());
            scrollPane.setBounds(200, 10, 150, 100);
            list.setSelectedIndex(10);
            list.addListSelectionListener(new ListHandler());
            table.setBounds(10, 150, 550, 200);
            model.setMonth(comboBox.getSelectedIndex() + 1998, list.getSelectedIndex());
            getContentPane().add(comboBox);
            getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
            table.setGridColor(Color.black);
            table.setShowGrid(true);
            getContentPane().add(table);

            this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            setSize(530,300);
            setVisible(true);


          }


    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Calendar frame = new Calendar();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public class ComboHandler implements ItemListener {
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
            System.out.println("ItemState change Method called ");
          model.setMonth(comboBox.getSelectedIndex() + 1998, list.getSelectedIndex());
          table.repaint();
        }
      }

      public class ListHandler implements ListSelectionListener {
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
          model.setMonth(comboBox.getSelectedIndex() + 1998, list.getSelectedIndex());
          table.repaint();
        }
      }
    }
    class CalendarModel extends AbstractTableModel {
      String[] days = { "Sun" , "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat" };

      int[] numDays = { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };

      String[][] calendar = new String[7][7];

      public CalendarModel() {

          //setting name of days (mon,tues)
        for (int i = 0; i < days.length; ++i)
        {
            System.out.println("day[i] *** "+days[i]);
            calendar[0][i] = days[i];

        }
        for (int i = 1; i < 7; ++i){
          for (int j = 0; j < 7; ++j)
          {
              System.out.println("calendar[i][j] value i ** "+i +" j value "+ j );
            calendar[i][j] = " ";
          }
        }

      }

      public int getRowCount() {
        return 7;
      }

      public int getColumnCount() {
        return 7;
      }

      public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {
          System.out.println("get Value at ** "+calendar[row][column]); 
        return calendar[row][column];
      }

      /*
      public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int column) {
          System.out.println("set Value at ** "+(String) value);
        calendar[row][column] = (String) value;
      }*/

      public void setMonth(int year, int month) {
        for (int i = 1; i < 7; ++i)
        {
          for (int j = 0; j < 7; ++j)
          {
            calendar[i][j] = " ";
          }
        }
        java.util.GregorianCalendar cal = new java.util.GregorianCalendar();
        cal.set(year, month, 1);
        int offset = cal.get(java.util.GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 1;
        offset += 7;
        int num = daysInMonth(year, month);
        for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i) {
            System.out.println("offset *** "+Integer.toString(i+1));
          calendar[offset / 7][offset % 7] = Integer.toString(i+1);
          ++offset;
        }
      }

      public boolean isLeapYear(int year) {
          System.out.println("Is Leap Year *** ");
        if (year % 4 == 0)
          return true;
        return false;
      }

      public int daysInMonth(int year, int month) {
          System.out.println("day In month*** ");
        int days = numDays[month];
        if (month == 1 && isLeapYear(year))
          ++days;
        System.out.println("days *** "+days);
        return days;
      }

}
```

Comment: please and your question is ???, interesting 5 upvotes to the question without any question inside

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if these are related but...

```
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {

    int index = comboBox.getSelectedIndex();
    System.out.println("index = " + index + "; " + (index + 1998));

    model.setMonth(comboBox.getSelectedIndex() + 1998, list.getSelectedIndex());
    table.repaint();
}
```

Doesn't produce results which match those that are listed within the combo box.  For example, if you select the first value, it will equal `1998`, not `2008`

So, if I select `2013` from the combo box, I'm actually getting `2003`.

When I changed it to

```
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {

    int index = comboBox.getSelectedIndex();
    System.out.println("index = " + index + "; " + (index + 2008));

    model.setMonth(comboBox.getSelectedIndex() + 2008, list.getSelectedIndex());
    table.repaint();
}
```

It gave me better results.

I also changed

```
java.util.GregorianCalendar cal = new java.util.GregorianCalendar();
```

to

```
java.util.Calendar cal = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
```

You should avoid making assumptions about the users calendar system if possible...

I'd also avoid `null` layouts as well ;)

You should also avoid calling `table.repaint` when you change the table model, instead try using `fireTableDataChanged` from within the `setMonth` method

I would, personally, add the listeners to the combobox and `JList` before setting there selected indexes, this will allow the listeners to update the model for you...

You'll also need to fix you `ListHandler` so that it uses `2008` instead `1998`

Comment: +1 avoiding NullLayout and JTable description, but I think (quite sure) that all good Java Calendars haven't any issue with ....

Answer (score 1):

Have a try with this in setMonth method

```
 public void setMonth(int year, int month)
```

Change

```
 calendar[offset / 7][offset % 7] = Integer.toString(i+1);
```

To

```
 calendar[offset / 7][offset % 7] = Integer.toString(i+2);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.. use  **- 2**  instead of **- 1** in offset calculation.

```
 java.util.GregorianCalendar cal = new java.util.GregorianCalendar();
    cal.set(year, month, 1);
    int offset = cal.get(java.util.GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)- 2 ;
    offset += 7;
    int num = daysInMonth(year, month);
    for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i) {
        System.out.println("offset *** "+Integer.toString(i+1));
      calendar[offset / 7][offset % 7] = Integer.toString(i+1);
      ++offset;
```

Comment: I have tried to replace offset -1 to -2 but its replacing week day saturday in column please provide me suggestions